# How do I stop spam messages?

Tags: 7, advertising

In my site with Drupal 7 spammers create a new block. What can I do to stop this?

Comment: _Electronic spamming is the use of electronic messaging systems to send unsolicited messages (spam), especially advertising, as well as sending messages repeatedly on the same site._ Once people can create blocks it is no longer spam and you have a bigger problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update Drupal to the latest version withing the major. (Drupal 7.43 is the latest for 7 major. https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.43.tar.gz)
2. Delete the users that spam.
3. If admin (uid 1) account was used to spam, change password. Check if email has been hijacked. If a wrong email is specified for admin user (uid 1), change it to yours before changing password.
4. If your site allows other users (a social network), check user permissions if they are allowed too much.
5. If you conclude that your site has in fact been seriously hacked and none above works, bring in a specialist to handle your specific problem.

There is also a walkthrough "Your Drupal site got hacked, now what?" at Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2365547